# Roid: if(); do not caused any prohibition

Tags: java, android, if-statement, syntax

I watched weird situation: I didn't get any error when used something like this in my Android app code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

        if (getActionBar().getSelectedTab().getPosition()==1)**;**
        {
            if ( getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Tag B") instanceof ContactsArchiveFragment)
            {
                    final ContactsArchiveFragment fragment = (ContactsArchiveFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Tag B");

                if (fragment.allowBackPressed()) { // and then you define a method allowBackPressed with the logic to allow back pressed or not

                    Log.i("calls act back cont archive", "on back clicked");
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }
            }

        }

}
```

When I tried to do something like this:

```
    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

        if (getActionBar().getSelectedTab().getPosition()==1);
        {
            if ( getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Tag B") instanceof ContactsArchiveFragment)
            {
                    final ContactsArchiveFragment fragment = (ContactsArchiveFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Tag B");

                if (fragment.allowBackPressed()) { // and then you define a method allowBackPressed with the logic to allow back pressed or not

                    Log.i("calls act back cont archive", "on back clicked");
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {

        }

}
```

I received `Syntax error on token "else", delete this token`. When I saw the semi, I reliazed what is the problem. But this wondered me, can someone explain what it is about?

Comment: @Answers: I believe he is asking why the `**;**` doesn't give him a compile error (appearantly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have just an `if` like that:

```
if();
{
    // Supposed to be with if
}
```

the block that was supposed to be with `if`, is now just a local block independent of `if`. The `if` statement ends at the semi-colon. Compiler wouldn't mark it as error, as it is perfectly a valid code.

Now with your 2nd case:

```
if ();
{

} else {

}
```

Note that the `if` statement has ended at semi-colon only, and then you have a block. But the `else` there is not coming just after any `if` as it is required to come. So, it is really an `else` without an `if`.

This is similar to the case when you will get an error in this code:

```
if () {

} 
System.out.println("Hello");
else {  // Error. Which `if` block do you suppose else to be bound with?

}
```

It's just that, the above case is quite obvious on first look. So it goes like:

```
if ();
```

can be visualized as:

```
if()
    ;  // Empty statement
```

which is equivalent to an empty `if` block - `if() { }`

Answer (score 7):

> But this wondered me, can someone explain what it is about?

Sure - the `;` is just an empty statement, and it's fine to have a block with no `if`. For example, this is valid:

```
if (i == 0)
    System.out.println("i was 0");

System.out.println("In top-level block");

{
    System.out.println("In a block");
}
```

... and the semi-colon after the `if` is just equivalent to the first `if` statement with an empty body.

Personally I *always* use braces for `if` statements (and `while` statements etc). Some compilers (e.g. the one built into Eclipse) allow you to trip a warning or error if you use an empty statement like this.

The `else` form isn't valid because you can only have an `else` clause as part of an `if`/`else` statement, whereas the `if` statement is already "done" at the end of the semi-colon.

Answer (score 1):

An extra `;`  causing all the mess here.

That semicolon terminates  the `statement` there ,And assuming it as a new block stating from  there.

If you see closely

```
  if (getActionBar().getSelectedTab().getPosition()==1);  <----
```

That is a statement,Not an If condtion.

condition should be

```
 if (getActionBar().getSelectedTab().getPosition()==1){


}
```

Remove that extra `;`

If you see the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)  related to blocks,

> A block is a group of zero or more statements between balanced braces and can be used anywhere a single statement is allowed. The following example, BlockDemo, illustrates the use of blocks:

```
class BlockDemo {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          boolean condition = true;
          if (condition) { // begin block 1
               System.out.println("Condition is true.");
          } // end block one
          else { // begin block 2
               System.out.println("Condition is false.");
          } // end block 2
     }
}
```